# How to display multiple images in custom field

Tags: custom-field, images

I'm using a plugin called Anonymous Pro that allows users to submit posts. Users can also submit multiple images into a post, which gets placed in a custom field, like so:

```
Array ( [0] => http://localhost/image1.jpg,http://localhost/image2.jpg,http://localhost/image3.jpg, )
```

How would I then display the above images on the frontend?

Comment: What's the `meta_key` ?

Comment: The meta_key can be configured to what you want. So at the moment it's **AP_post_image**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we are viewing some king of single - post, page, custom post type etc.

```
<?php

$imgs_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'AP_post_image', true );
if ( '' != $imgs_meta ) {
  $imgs = explode( ',', $imgs_meta );

  foreach ( $imgs as $src )
    printf( '<img src="%s" />', esc_url( $src ) );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately it does not work though, it shows up as: `<img src="http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image1.jpg,http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image2.jpg,http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image3.jpg">`, and not in individual image tags

Comment: Show us output of `var_dump( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'AP_post_image' ) );`

Comment: `array (size=1)
  0 => string 'http://localhost/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image1.jpg,http://localhos‌​t/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/image2.jpg,http://localhost/site/wp-content/upl‌​oads/2015/03/image3.jpg'`

Comment: try code in updated answer